# Finding the derivative of a plot given two axis - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics

I have a list of the x-axis and another list of the y-axis values and currently I am finidng the derivative of the gradient as such:

```
from pylab import polyfit

x = [0,2,3,4]
y = [23,4,34,67]

(m,__) = polyfit(x,y,1)
print m
```

If I don't want to rely on the pylab/scipy polyfit, how else could I get the deriative?

Comment: Just one more example of why pylab causes more harm than good.

Comment: i didn't want extra packages in the code.

Comment: You are importing numpy _anyway_ with pylab, and to quote the zen of python, 'explicit is better than implicit'.

Comment: is there a way to not even do it with `numpy`?

Comment: Linear least squares is just some matrix operations.  If you want to write your own matrix inversion, go for it, but you should use numpy arrays, so you might as well use their polyfit as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matplotlib.pylab` includes numpy for you, so just use the function `numpy.polyfit` directly:

```
import numpy as np

x = [0,2,3,4]
y = [23,4,34,67]

m, __ = np.polyfit(x, y, 1)
print m
```